# Input values not resetting - vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a level 2 input field component that i am using. I want to reset on button click from the parent component. I am trying to pass the data to base initial input field and then emitting back to the parent.

My question is that when i try to reset the data on button click the value from the parent component its not working.
Data is not set to null and the values remain as 123.

What wrong I am doing in the following code.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Base Input**

```
<template>
  <input
    v-model="myValue"
    type="number"
    inputmode="numeric"
    @input="$emit( 'input', $event.target.value )"
  />
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        myValue: undefined
      };
    }
  }
 };
</script>
```

**Level 01**

```
<template>
  <div class="c-floating-label">
    <input-number @input="passValue" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import InputNumber from '../../atoms/form-controls/BaseInput';
  export default {
    components: {
      InputNumber
    }
    methods: {
      passValue: function (value) {
        this.$emit('input', value);
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

**Main Component**

```
<div>
  <level-01 
    :required="true"
    :v-model="datax.cardNumber"
    value="datax.cardNumber"
   />
 <button @click="reset">click me</button>
</div>
<script>
   data () {
      return {
        datax: {
          cardNumber: undefined
        }
      };
    },
   created() {
      this.datax.cardNumber = 123;
    },
    methods: {
      reset () {
        this.datax.cardNumber = null;
      },
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed binding on MainComponent

```
<level-01 
  :required="true"
  :v-model="datax.cardNumber"
  :value="datax.cardNumber"
 />
```

Note :value="datax.cardNumber" is correct
Second, in level-01 you do not bind value prop (not defined at all)

```
<template>
  <div class="c-floating-label">
    <input-number @input="passValue" :value="$attrs.value"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import InputNumber from '../../atoms/form-controls/BaseInput';
  export default {
    components: {
      InputNumber
    },
    methods: {
      passValue: function (value) {
        this.$emit('input', value);
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

And finally BaseComponent:

```
<template>
  <input
    :value="$attrs.value"
    type="number"
    inputmode="numeric"
    @input="$emit( 'input', $event )"
  />
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        // myValue: undefined
      };
    }
  }
 };
</script>
```

Comment: I use $attrs here, It is better to define props strictly. In BaseComponent you do not need to keep state (myVakue). In @input event the $event is your real value, not the target